# Select values from vector using Date as index

Tags: r, xts

Suppose I have a named vector, `bar`:

```
bar=c()
bar["1997-10-14"]=1
bar["2001-10-14"]=2
bar["2007-10-14"]=1
```

How can I select from `bar` all values for which the index is within a specific date range? So, if I look for all values between `"1995-01-01"` and `"2000-06-01"`, I should get `1`. And similarly for the period between `"2001-09-01"` and `"2007-11-04"`, I should get `2` and `1`.

Comment: FYI: You are creating a named numeric vector, not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has been solved for good with the [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/packages=xts) package which extends functionality from the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/packages=zoo) package.

```
R> library(xts)
Loading required package: zoo
R> bar <- xts(1:3, order.by=as.Date("2001-01-01")+365*0:2)
R> bar
           [,1]
2001-01-01    1
2002-01-01    2
2003-01-01    3
R> bar["2002::"]        ## open range with a start year
           [,1]
2002-01-01    2
2003-01-01    3
R> bar["::2002"]        ## or end year
           [,1]
2001-01-01    1
2002-01-01    2
R> bar["2002-01-01"]    ## or hits a particular date
           [,1]
2002-01-01    2
R>
```

There is a lot more here -- but the basic point is do **not** operate on strings masquerading as dates.

Use a `Date` type, or preferably even an extension package built to efficiently index on millions of dates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your dates from characters into a `Date` type with `as.Date()` (or a POSIX type if you have more information like the time of day). Then you can make comparisons with standard [relational operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator) such as <= and >=.

You should consider using a timeseries package such as `zoo` for this.

*Edit*:

Just to respond to your comment, here's an example of using dates with your existing vector:

```
> as.Date(names(bar)) < as.Date("2001-10-14")
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> bar[as.Date(names(bar)) < as.Date("2001-10-14")]
1997-10-14 
         1
```

Although you really should just use a time series package.  Here's how you could do this with `zoo` (or `xts`, `timeSeries`, `fts`, etc.):

```
library(zoo)
ts <- zoo(c(1, 2, 1), as.Date(c("1997-10-14", "2001-10-14", "2007-10-14")))
ts[index(ts) < as.Date("2001-10-14"),]
```

Since the index is now a `Date` type, you can make as many comparisons as you want.  Read the `zoo` vignette for more information.

Comment: Hmmm, I might be doing it wrong but if I do something like bar[as.Date("2001-10-14")] I get very strange results involving a lot of NAs

Answer (score 1):

Using fact that dates are in lexical order:

```
bar[names(bar) > "1995-01-01" & names(bar) < "2000-06-01"]
# 1997-10-14 
#          1 

bar[names(bar) > "2001-09-01" & names(bar) < "2007-11-04"]
# 2001-10-14 2007-10-14 
#          2          1
```

Result is named vector (as you original `bar`, it's not a list it's named vector).

As Dirk states in his answer it's better to use `Date` for efficiency reasons. Without external packages you could rearrange you data and create two vectors (or two-column `data.frame`) one for dates, one for values:

```
bar_dates <- as.Date(c("1997-10-14", "2001-10-14", "2007-10-14"))
bar_values <- c(1,2,1)
```

then use simple indexing:

```
bar_values[bar_dates > as.Date("1995-01-01") & bar_dates < as.Date("2000-06-01")]
# [1] 1

bar_values[bar_dates > as.Date("2001-09-01") & bar_dates < as.Date("2007-11-04")]
# [1] 2 1
```